# MDAS rule GLITCHED?

Tags: arithmetic

I always get confused with this kind of math problem, How do we solve this problem?

Example:

```
1 * 5 - 10 + 2 = ?
```

Solution 1 [My solution]:

Of couse I use MDAS rule

```
(1 * 5) - 10 + 2

5 - (10 + 2)

5 - 12

-7
```

Solution 2 [My prof]:

```
(1 * 5) - 10 + 2

5 (-10 + 2)

5 - 8

-3
```

The difference in our soution is I did not include the subtraction sign and my prof include it what is the rules in solving that kind of problem?

Comment: The step that says $5 (-10 +2)$ should really say $5 + (-10 + 2)$.  You did the calculations correctly in solution 2, but that step is written as multiplication and not addition.

Comment: A does not precede S. They should be applied in the order in which they are given, from left to right.

Comment: What was wrong with the answer in the comment at MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/245267/mdas-solution-glitch

Comment: Learn to read that as $1\cdot 5+(-10)+2$; after the multiplication you have $5+(-10)+2=-5+2=-3$. In other words, forget about subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st solution is wrong : in $5-10+2$, $5-10$ is before $10+2$ so 
$$5-10+2 = (5-10)+2 = -5+2 = -3$$

When you have only additions and substractions, priority rule is given by the order of appearance of the different operations from left to right.

Comment: To add more detail, $5 - (10 + 2)$ is not the same as $5 - 10 + 2$ precisely because of MDAS.  Adding parentheses on the $10 + 2$ changes the order in which things are done (as paf explained) and $5 - (10 +2)$ is actually the same as $5 - 10 - 2$ after we distribute.